# Duplicate model-objects when save plugins in django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I started to use django-cms and have some problems.

**First problem:**

When I save page with my plugin (`CMSServicesListPlugin`), in admin-side I see the duplicates of the related objects. They have identical id. How hide duplicates or better how disable creating it

**Second problem:**

When I change the plugin with ForeignKey-field to `cms.Page` (`CMSBannerWithImagePlugin`), I see the duplicates of Page in select. How resolve it problem?

My models:

```
# models.py

class Service(models.Model):

    title =             models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)

class ServicePluginRelation(models.Model):

    service =           models.ForeignKey('services.Service', blank=False, null=False, related_name='relations')
    plugin =            models.ForeignKey('services.ServicesListPlugin', blank=False, null=False, related_name='relations')

class ServicesListPlugin(CMSPlugin):

    title =             models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    services =          models.ManyToManyField('services.Service', related_name='plugins', blank=False, null=False, through=ServicePluginRelation)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):

        for relation in oldinstance.relations.all() :
            relation.plugin = self
            relation.pk = None
            relation.id = None
            relation.save()

class BannerWithImage(CMSPlugin):

    image =         models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='links/link_with_image/image')    
    page =          models.ForeignKey('cms.Page', blank=False, null=False)
```

And pugins:

```
# cms_plugins.py

class ServicePluginRelationInlineAdmin(SortableTabularInline):

    model = ServicePluginRelation

class CMSServicesListPlugin(CMSPluginBase):

    model =     ServicesListPlugin    
    inlines = (ServicePluginRelationInlineAdmin,)

    def get_render_template(self, context, instance, placeholder):

        return 'services/services_list.html'

class CMSBannerWithImagePlugin(CMSPluginBase):

    model =     BannerWithImage

    render_template =   'links/link_with_image.html'
```

Thanx!

Comment: show your CMSPluginBase

Comment: @Sławek It's django-cms class https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/plugin_base.py#L95

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misconception with people new to CMS.

Once you publish a page, a copy of it & everything (plugins etc) attached to it is created as the 'live' version.

You can then make edits to the page which are held in the draft version of the page, with the draft version of attached plugins etc. Once that draft version is published, a new copy replaces the old live version. Take a look at the [publishing docs](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/publishing.html).

Don't worry about this & don't expose plugin models to the admin because they should be edited via the CMS frontend.

Comment: Ok, but what about duplicating the related objects (`Service`). They are not edited via CMS frontend but cloning after each plugin save

Comment: I'm not so sure, because you've included in the `ServicePluginRelation` as an inline to your plugin. I'd have to see things running & see the database to be sure, but I think it's still a case of a draft & live version because you've hooked that inline.